# How to mock and test third-party React components that are sub-components in a library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I may not be using the right word here, but I have a component that uses `react-icons` and particular the Font Awesome ones.

```js
import { FaDog, FaHome, FaFileContract } from "react-icons/fa";
```

And I pass them as components to a child component.

```js
<SidebarBtn label="Home" linkTo="/" icon={<FaHome />}></SidebarBtn>
```

As I write the Jest unit test, I want to make sure those react-icon components are called and passed to the child...but it does not seem to pass like I would think.

```js
const mockFaHome = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-icons/fa", () => () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("react-icons/fa"),
    FaHome: () => {
      mockFaHome();
      return <div />;
    }
  };
});

  test("renders the sidebar", () => {
    const tree = render(<Sidebar />);
    expect(mockSidebarBtn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
    expect(mockSidebarBtn).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, {
      label: "Home",
      linkTo: "/",
      icon: expect.anything(),
    });
    expect(mockFaHome).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

It does not pass because the mock does not get called.

In Jest, how can I test this? That these sub-components of react-icons get passed as props to child components?

Comment: In this case, maybe Snapshot test will be easier?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not mock the third-part UI/component library and test the implementation detail, such as asserting some method to be called or not.

From the [RTL doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/migrate-from-enzyme#why-should-i-use-the-react-testing-library):

> Users don't care what happens behind the scenes. They just see and interact with the output. So, instead of accessing the components' internal API, or evaluating the state, you'll get more confidence by writing your tests based on the component output.

Test the implementation details will cause:

> every small change requires rewriting some part of your tests, even if the change you made does not affect the component's output

You should test and assert what the component is rendered, standing in the user's perspective. If your component is presentable, you can use snapshot testing to ensure its UI hierarchy.

Note: That's not to say you can't mock，if the component is complex or has IO operations, side effects methods, we can mock them.